# PHP ArrayInteger

Tags: php, arrays

I have some code like this :

```
$category['ProductDataBaseXML'] = [
      '_attributes' => [
      'version' => $version,
      'lastupdate' => $lastupdate
    ],
];
```

While I use `array_push` on other methods, it shown that `$category` was scalar type, tried get type data :

```
echo gettype($category);
```

It shown `ArrayInteger`. May I know what I'm missing info about `ArrayInteger` vs `Array` ?

Also i have some questions while

```
$category = [];

$category = array_push($category, "a");
```

> array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, int given

May I know what missing in here ?

Thank you a lot

Comment: Can you show all your code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This output doesn't seems correct. It returns correctly type as array.

```
$category['ProductDataBaseXML'] = [
      '_attributes' => [
      'version' => $version,
      'lastupdate' => $lastupdate
    ],
];

echo gettype($category);
```

Gives array as output.

For,

$category = array_push($category, "a");

You are reassigning $category with return value of array_push(), which is the new number of elements in the array.

So now $category type is integer.

Comment: I'm on it. Thank you for reply

Answer (score 0):

Check, work fine:

```
  $category = []; 
  $category['ProductDataBaseXML'] = [
      '_attributes' => [
      'version' => $version,
      'lastupdate' => $lastupdate
    ],
  ];
 array_push($category, "a");
 print_r( $category );
```